# Is postgresql's ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE expected to generate lots of dead tuples?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have an ETL process from one postgres table to another in which we use an INSERT / ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE approach to essentially merge one large dataset into an existing dataset, using a unique constraint on a couple columns as the conflict checker.

When the new rows are inserted and conflicts happen, we update a couple columns on the existing row, but leave it mostly intact.  In many cases, the set of rows being inserted will be ALL conflicts with existing rows and so the whole statement is basically a merge of new values in just those couple columns but without any actual new rows being inserted.

Looking a `pg_stat_user_tables` we are noticing that this strategy is causing a lot of dead tuples to appear which require vacuuming.  This is counter-intuitive as one would assume that the conflict just results in an UPDATE to the existing row but there is no dead row created or deleted, but the stats coming out of `pg_stat_user_tables` seem to contradict that.

By contrast, if we change all the statements to be ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING then this dead tuple problem goes away.

Is it normal to expect a lot of dead tuple accumulation as a result of using ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE?

We're using postgres 9.5 and 9.6 although both seem to behave the same.

Comment: It's normal, see [Does updating a row with the same value actually update the row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118214/38456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All updates create dead tuples. That's how MVCC works in PostgreSQL.

Autovacuum will clean them up later.